# seekbar saved but not text

Tags: java, android, android-studio

im trying to create an activity consist of seekbar, sharedpreferences and text.

just simple idea as i am still learning about this.

the idea was to create a seekbar, progressing with text size, including the sharedpreferences to save the current size.

however, the only saved was the seekbar progress, not the text. can anyone help, or giving ideas to me as im still new to this.

here the java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class fontsize extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{



    int textSize = 30;

    TextView textViewFont, textViewSize;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;



    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fontsize);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fontresize", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        int progress = sharedPreferences.getInt("progress", 0);





        //definingtextview

        textViewFont = findViewById(R.id.textViewFont);
        textViewSize = findViewById(R.id.textViewSize);




        //seekbar

        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize); // size 30sp
        textViewSize.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax()); // 0/30

        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int progressNew = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                textSize = textSize + (progress - progressNew);
                progressNew = progress;
                textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize);
                editor.putInt("progress", progress);
                editor.apply();



            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });

        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout4);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view4);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_dehaze_24);

        //navdrawermenu

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(fontsize.this, home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            case R.id.nav_fontsize:
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of storing the progress, You will need to store the textSize in preference.
Like this : editor.putInt("textSize", textSize);

Comment: it does work with seekbar but not saving the font size. can you add on answer section ?

Comment: what you exactly mean by "it does work with seekbar but not saving the font size" ?

Comment: it does saving the progress of seekbar. however, the font size does not save. i found the answer, it is just my newbie error. i provide it below.

Comment: if you dont mind, u can help me on my new question, on how to retrieve sharedpreferences on other activity, particularly font size on my current issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer. I know it just simple newbies error. so here it is

```
textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize); // size 30sp
```

in this line , I must add the `getProgress` in order to include the `settextsize` value in the progress.

so it must be

```
textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize+seekBar.getProgress()); // size 30sp
```